# Should I have Wireless if I'm testing Ubuntu on my laptop via usb?

Tags: wireless, live-usb

I am no tech wiz, that's why I'm here.

I have successfully(or so I think) installed Ubuntu onto a USB and have booted my laptop with the disk. I have successfully gotten the prompt to try it out, or install...

I click try; everything looks great except I can't connect to the internet.  Should I be able to?  If so, the file is corrupt?  If not then ill probably install next to my current server.

Any thoughts would be great,

D

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, you are supposed to be able to connect to either a wireless or wired network with a the `LiveUSB/LiveCD` (trial Ubuntu).

**In the case of a wireless adapter**, you're gonna need the correct driver installed for it. In my case, the `Additional Drivers` window popped up several minutes after the system booted into the LiveUSB/LiveCD, and I was able to install the wireless adapter driver without downloading anything.

Try starting the `Additional Drivers` window by clicking on the `power icon` on the top right corner, clicking on `"System Settings"`, and followed by `"Additional Drivers"`

**Edit:**
I assumed you promptly tested the hardware switch for WiFi before posting here. If you didn't, it's a good idea to try it. (Credit goes to [@pfeiffep](https://askubuntu.com/users/130284/pfeiffep))